# Appium SendKey issue

Tags: appium, sendkeys, appium-android

I am facing issues when using sendkeys with appium below are the details

> Appium version -1.3.4.1 ,java client - java-client-2.1.0 ,android
>   Device - Samsung Galaxy S4(Phone) ,Android Version - 4.4.2
>
> Application under test - flipkart/Wego  android Application

Q. when i am using sendKeys to send a sting value in the Edit view what is happening is

1. sometime string value entered is "correct" -Mumbai
2. but sometime string value entered is "not correct" -Mmbai

here is my code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.wego.android:id/flight_search_location_textview']")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
```

please help as I am stuck here and do not know what to do

Comment: it's string not sting

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am trying to enter **abcd123** but it sometimes types **abcd 12**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Webelement enterText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.wego.android:id/flight_search_location_textview']"));

enterText.sendKeys("Mumbai");

Comment: Thanks @ Gary your solution is working fine ,thanks for the help,can you plz tell me the difference between these two line if possible 1.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.wego.android:id/flight_search_location_textview']")).sendKeys("Mumbai") and 2.Webelement enterText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@resource-id='com.wego.android:id/flight_search_location_textview']"));

enterText.sendKeys("Mumbai"); i mean why 1. was showing error some time  ,i mean whhats the difference between the two

Comment: the only difference is we are creating a webelement "enterText" and then passing value instead of passing directly to the locator.

Comment: since i am using Page Object Model, this solution didn't help me. Do you have any alternative solution? @Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

you can try this type of code, i use python

```
 emailSign = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("UIATextField")
 passSign = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("UIASecureTextField")

        passSign.click()

        emailSign.send_keys(username + carriage_return)
        passSign.send_keys(password + carriage_return)
```

Comment: Thanks @ krishna chetan for the quick reply but can you provide some work around in java ?

Comment: Did you try using selecting element by id and then sending keys ?
I saw you used Xpath, try sending keys by using id of the element

Comment: No i have not tried it yet i will definitely try it and share my experience @krishna chetan